# Magento 2: how to add a block in cart under cart summary?

Tags: magento2, frontend, static-block, design, widgets

It's **possible to use a widget to insert a block inside the cart summary (at the bottom)**.

However I'd like to add a block **under** the cart summary.

I've already created a custom theme which inherits from Blank theme.

Answer (score 3):

We can use Widget: **CONTENT > Widgets**

**1)Mini Cart:**

In **Layout Updates**:

- we can choose **Display on > All Pages**
- choose **Container** > **Mini-cart promotion**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

**2)Checkout Cart page:**

In Layout Updates:

- we can choose **Display on > Specified Page**
- choose **Page > Shopping Cart** and **Container > Cart Summary Container**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Your solution adds a block inside the Summary block. However I want to add it outside the block, under it.

Comment: May I misunderstood your question. However, I think in this case, we can use layout. There are some Widget settings, but may not meet your requirement.

Comment: Do you know how to do it using layout?

Comment: how to add before order Total?

Answer (score 0):

```
<referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.totals.container">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="checkout.cart.countdown" after="-" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/count.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

you can use this reference inside **checkout_cart_index.xml**

but you should use some other class for widget instead of this `class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"`